# spring ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: spring, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

This is the Oracle procedure I'm trying to call:

```
 PROCEDURE GetCoreReportExtras
( pnAssignment IN NUMBER,
  pnUserRole in NUMBER,
  psAreaMenu in VARCHAR2,
  pnAreaLevel in NUMBER,
  curReportList OUT outcur,
  psLDO in VARCHAR2 default 'none',
  pnAcisNumber in NUMBER default 0);
```

Here's my Java code:

```
private class GetStandardReportExtrasSPV2{
    int nAreaLevel;
    int nAssignment;
    int nUserRole;
    int nAcisNum = 0;
    String strAreaMenu;     
    String strLDO = null;

    private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall procGetReportExtras;

    public GetStandardReportExtrasSPV2(DataSource ds, int nUserRole, String strAreaMenu,
            int nAssignment, int nAreaLevel, String strLDO, int nAcisNum) {

        this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(ds);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        this.procGetReportExtras =
                new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                    .withCatalogName("package")
                    .withProcedureName("proc")
                    .returningResultSet(REPORT_LIST,
                                ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Report.class));

    }

    public List<Report> getReportsList() {

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put(USER_ASSIGNMENT, nAssignment);
        params.put(USER_ROLE, nUserRole);
        params.put(AREA_MENU, strAreaMenu);
        params.put(AREA_LEVEL, nAreaLevel);
        params.put(SEGMENT, strLDO);
        params.put(ACIS_NUMBER, nAcisNum);

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValues(params);

        Map m = procGetReportExtras.execute(new HashMap<String, Object>(0), in);
        return (List) m.get(REPORT_LIST);
    }

}
```

When getReportsList() calls execute(), I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>     org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters(CallMetaDataContext.java:555)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters(AbstractJdbcCall.java:419)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:364)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:173)

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```
Map m = procGetReportExtras.execute(new HashMap<String, Object>(0), in);
```

You are calling the [overloaded](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#execute%28java.lang.Object...%29) method that takes in a `Object ...`. This method takes

> optional array containing the in parameter values to be used in the
>   call. Parameter values must be provided in the same order as the
>   parameters are defined for the stored procedure.

In your call, those two parameters happen to be an empty `HashMap` and a `SqlParameterSource`.

The call fails in `CallMetaDataContext#matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters()`. Source:

```
public Map<String, ?> matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters(Object[] parameterValues) {
    Map<String, Object> matchedParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(parameterValues.length);
    int i = 0;
    for (SqlParameter parameter : this.callParameters) {
        if (parameter.isInputValueProvided()) {
            String parameterName =  parameter.getName();
            matchedParameters.put(parameterName, parameterValues[i++]); // fails here
        }
    }
    return matchedParameters;
}
```

It's expecting that the array you pass has 7 elements (because that's what your stored procedure expects), but it only has 2, the `HashMap` and the `SqlParameterSource`. When it tries to access the 3rd one (index 2), it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You probably wanted to use the [`execute()` method that accepts an `SqlParameterSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#execute%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource%29)

```
Map m = procGetReportExtras.execute(in);
```

Comment: OK, I'm past the ArrayOutOfBoundsException.  Now I'm getting: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call PKG_RPT_STE_DATA.GETCOREREPORTEXTRAS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cursor is closed.;

Comment: Please ask another question and provide the full body of the procedure. I don't know Oracle...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong `SimpleJDBCCall.execute(Object... args)`; use `SimpleJDBCCall.execute(SqlParameterSource)`

```
procGetReportExtras.execute(in);
```