# SimpleJdbcCall ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I call SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SqlParameterSource) and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537576/spring-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-with-simplejdbccall) response and the solution is to call the SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SqlParameterSource) method... which I'm already doing. Any help would be much appreciated.

The UserBean login method which fails on the last line:

```
public static UserBean login(UserBean bean){
    String userName = bean.getUserName();
    String password = bean.getPassword();
    String salt = "";
    String returnStatus = "";
    SqlParameterSource paramSource;
    Map<String, String> namedParams;
    Map<String, Object> outMap;
    MessageDigest digest;

    SimpleJdbcCall saltJDBCCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withProcedureName("getSalt")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    SimpleJdbcCall loginJDBCCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withProcedureName("userLogin")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

    namedParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    namedParams.put("inLoginName", userName);
    paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(namedParams);
    outMap = saltJDBCCall.execute(paramSource);
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSalt(
IN inLoginName VARCHAR(30),
OUT returnStatus VARCHAR(10),
OUT returnMessage VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT loginName
    FROM EndUser
    WHERE loginName = inLoginName)
THEN
    SELECT  'PASS' INTO returnStatus;
    SELECT salt INTO returnMessage
        FROM EndUser
        WHERE loginName = inLoginName
        LIMIT 1;
ELSE
    SELECT  'FAIL' INTO returnStatus;
    SELECT  'Invalid user name or password.' INTO returnMessage;
END IF;
END//
```

The log which is less than helpful:

```
INFO: Server startup in 7965 ms
Nov 26, 2016 2:28:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2d55419c: startup date [Sat Nov 26 14:28:52 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 26, 2016 2:28:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Nov 26, 2016 2:28:52 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Edit: Yes, I saw the 'duplicate' thread as well. When I step through the code the last line throws that exception. The next one doesn't get reached. I've surrounded that statement with a try-catch block and put up the stack trace [here](http://textuploader.com/d5bra) but that's not much help to me either.

Edit: Alright. I ***finally*** have a solution. The below line:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall saltJDBCCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withProcedureName("getSalt")
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
```

Should be:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall saltJDBCCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withProcedureName("getSalt")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .useInParameterNames("inLoginName")
        .declareParameters(
            new SqlParameter("inLoginName", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlOutParameter("returnStatus", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlOutParameter("returnMessage", Types.VARCHAR));
```

Apparently Spring isn't quite smart enough to register the parameters itself. You still have to do that yourself.

Comment: The given code cannot throw this exception. And there is also nothing in the logs showing that that's the faulty method. The logs show that the exception was swallowed: just the message was printed, not the stack trace. There must be code in your application doing that.

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread as well. I though that since the exception wasn't being thrown by my code it wasn't really applicable. When I debug and step through that method the last line is the one that's throws that error. That method that I'm calling is defined by the [SimpleJdbcCall API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) with nothing custom about it as far as I know. I surrounded the statement with a try-catch block and got the stacktrace [here](http://textuploader.com/d5bra). To me that's still less than helpful.